# Clear selection, select none

Tags: applescript, osx-mavericks

How can I clear the selection of a Finder item. I just updated to Mavericks from Snow Leopard and in Snow Leopard if you pressed esc, it would clear the current selection. Like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 53
```

How is this done in Mavericks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do it in pure Applescript would be:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selection to {}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it.

Hold Option and select "Deselect All" from Finder's "Edit" menu. Alternatively just use the shortcut Option+Cmd+A.

So as AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "a" using {command down, option down}
```

source: http://www.codez4mac.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=212&t=72255